# OCR using tess-two library returning incorrect text

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am using [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library for implementing OCR in my android application. The code I am using is:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);    
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight()/2);       

            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            //eng.traineddata
             baseApi.init(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "eng", TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
             baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
             String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

             Log.d("Recognized Text", recognizedText);

             baseApi.end();
```

This is the string I got after scan-

```
'r8''_, IIFP"" >- .
_ ~11 r-- _ _
3} .
' at H k
CO' f
ty, . s
_ 1 V Fre 111'};
_ _ 011g
I .1. ' Q
h.
```

which is not at all correct. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong here. I have downloaded the language data for english. There are few similar questions on SO but nothing could help me. My code seems to be correct. I have been struggling with this since two days. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Image scanned:
[image]

Comment: Would you attach a copy of the image you're trying to OCR?

Comment: @rmtheis: I added the image. When I scan the same image using your sample app- https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr. It reads data correctly.

Comment: Hi-.. I want to implement the tess two library. but i am unable run code as it tells " java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader ....."expecting ur help

Comment: @Biplab: It would be better if you post this as a new question. There are more chances that you'll get help that way.

Comment: Hi, I need to scan small text(Textsize nearly 8 to 10sp) from the hard copy(hard copy like current bills,etc...). I am using this github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr Project. How to scan smaller text ?I am struck here.Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue was image saved was rotated by 90 degrees and that's why code was unable to recognize the text correctly. Rotating bitmap by -90 degrees did the trick. Now the text is being recognized correctly.